# Android TextView multiple line problem (remove gab in second line)

Tags: android, xml, textview

[image]

There are two TextView and the second TextView is multiple lines.
But there is a gap in front of the second line. I would like to make as below

```
UserName Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World
```

Please give me some advice.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't do it directly you need to use the below the library

```
https://github.com/deano2390/FlowTextView
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this behavior programmatically with a single text view by appending user name and the long text together using SpannableString. I am sharing an example below for you to have a look.

**your_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_regular"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="test text" />
    

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and in your class you can append strings like this:

**YourActivity**

```
val userNameText = "User name "
val normalText = "Your long text Your long text Your long text Your long text"
val str = SpannableString(userNameText + normalText)
str.setSpan(
         StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD),
         0,
         boldText.length,
         Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
      )

txt_title.text = str
```

That's it. You will exactly get what you are looking for and in addition you can put any styling to your string.

Answer (score 0):

Use only 1 textview.

textView.setText(UserName Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World);